Solana Top 10 HOLDERS : how?
how to calculate the percentage of the top 10 holders.
example for this liquidity pool: 84Nu43GsHLaCDuVSvgiTwpQDTNhYejKFEkJmeXBFJmqQ
BaseMint: 4sp2EUDrQf46rZun6sYAWzjrXwUpx2T3njuoKmV766RJ
By getTokenLargestAccounts I get a list
Holder 1 : Address : UrZgM7x777PYsC3SrNLi1vekVAu5cLScSFnmc5jeJtY, Tokens : 65970000, Percent : 6%
Holder 2: Address: CxnQ5bbucVg7aKoPvaV32NshDrp6rNgTog4To42LAL7, Tokens: 34030000, Percent: 3%.
Holder 3: Address: DRWQsj4hANod7KpxyXDSRUswgDNFuTawnjp5fysx8Ad, Tokens: 33162691, Percent: 3%.
Cardholder 4: Address: k6RaLymUz6j1WUMvCFeUaMNdsxDZQeCyvDj5Nwvt8eT, Tokens: 30000000, Percent: 3%
Holder 5: Address: AhG9TeN3FEMAuGghuTZcBG9T6tqfEQ34ix9CAXcTGKXk, Tokens: 27576931, Percentage: 2%
Cardholder 6: Address: HpibBVtkCCLnYRHEPFssWYCQUk3cuNKh9iU7zZYFbRtQ, Tokens: 24889612, Percentage: 2%
Holder 7: Address: ieYLeoNBFs5Gjq4TjJa52cHiFbrh8uGBrbH1RoRfWKb, Tokens: 12824681, Percentage: 1%
Holder 8 : Address : CvVBgzw6zS9gzmnn1Vm9VvPFapBGJSFWsDy5Z4HBUSFm, Tokens : 10001788, Percentage : 1
Holder 9 : Address : FHbyMXVCCN9QDruvipg48fETDFiLGbQhLrsbgd88un8, Tokens : 10000000, Percentage : 1%
on dexscreener I no longer have the owner addresses but I can't find the owner from the account address and I think we need to filter on a few addresses to remove raydium and certainly others.
